# Microsoft Dynamics CRM - Adding leads to campaign | C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am new to microsoft dynamics crm. So my program creates leads in the crm system, so i have all of their guids. Also I have a campaign in the crm system whose guid I can retrieve. I want to add the leads to the campaign? So that they appear as campaign member when I open the campaign entity. I have come across codes that add dynamic and static lists to the campaign (using AddItemCampaignRequest), however, my assumption that leads are entities, so how can we add leads to the campaign (using C#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "campaign_leads" relationship and associate leads with the campaign:

```
var leadGuids = new List<Guid>(); //fetched lead GUIDs
service.Associate("campaign", campaignGuid, new Relationship("campaign_leads"),
            new EntityReferenceCollection(leadGuids.Select(lead => new EntityReference("lead", lead)).ToList()));
```

Comment: Firstly, Thanks for getting back. Second, I am not sure if I can create new Campaign or new Lead directly. I mean, in all my code, I have created them as an entity first, and when I tried to use the above code, it's showing errors as it fails to find reference to "Lead" and "Campaign"

Also , I don't see "campaign_leads" property in its documentation or metadata. Any other suggestions ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309509.aspx

Comment: I don't think you are using CRM  early bound entity classes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx) which has strongly typed entity objects like "Lead", "Campaign", I have updated my answer to reflect late bound entity types. "campaign_leads" is the relationship schema name, you can find it under 1:N relationships on campaign. The link you have referenced outlines a list of supported SDK messages, not the list of attributes and relationships on the entity.

Comment: Updated the answer with a cleaner way of associating leads to campaign entity, without using early bound entity classes.

Comment: and for single lead, would it be

service.Associate("campaign", camp_id, new Relationship("campaign_leads"),
                                    new Entity("lead",lead_id));   ??

Comment: It would be:                                                               service.Associate("campaign", campaignGuid, new Relationship("campaign_leads"),
                new EntityReferenceCollection(new[] {new EntityReference("lead", lead_id)}));